# Finding the Last Row and using it in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am dealing with a sheet of data that has multiple rows ans columns. Each time the macro runs, the number of rows can be different, so I am trying to find the last row for a column.

With the last row, I am trying to do a calculation. For example: if the row I get is 1200, I can do A1200/A2-1. MY code should explicitly paste the formula in an output worksheet and currently (currently I have to put the last row myself).

Question: How can I get the last row and put it in a formula? Should I assign it to a variable and then use the variable in the formula?

Lines of code I am using:

```
Sub Output()
Dim LastRowA As Long

LastRowA = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'this is my current method, it works using specific cells.
'I would like to change the D1662, for example, for a floating reference that gets the last row

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C2").Formula = "='TIME SERIES'!D1662/'TIME SERIES'!D2-1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes - just concatenate the `LastRowA` variable into the formula string: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C2").Formula = "='TIME SERIES'!D" & LastRowA & "/'TIME SERIES'!D2-1"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly the same answer as below. Unfortunately I cannot accept two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so. Just remove the variable from the quotes.

```
Sub Output()

Dim LastRowA As Long

LastRowA = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'this is my current method, it works using specific cells.
'I would like to change the D1662, for example, for a floating reference that gets the last row

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C2").Formula = "='TIME SERIES'!D" & LastRowA & "/'TIME SERIES'!D2-1"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no idea, I was doing something similar, but for some reason the code was commenting out the 'Time Series'. Have no idea why that does not happens in yours, but nonetheless, it works.

Comment: The single quote is a comment indicator so maybe you had accidentally left something out of the quotes.

Comment: I found out, mine was "= 'TIME SERIES'!D", there was a space after the = sign.

Comment: VBA is very fussy!

Answer (score 1):

How about a user defined function? This way you can add it to your equation in excel with `=LastRow(ColumnNumber)`. You can leave this in the vba editor and in excel set you cell value to "`=LastRowValue("SheetName",1)/A2-1`" where 1 would be column A.

```
Function LastRowValue(WorksheetName As String, Col As Long) As Long
'=======================================================================
'This can be typed into an excel cell as a normal function
'"=LastRow("SheetName",ColumnNumber)" The Column Number is indexed 
'starting with A=1 so C=3 and AA=27. Enter the WorksheetName in
'quotes "WorksheetName".
'========================================================================
Dim LR As Long

'LR will find the last row in column number "col" in WorksheetName.
LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WorksheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

'LastRowValue will be the output of this function and will be the value of 
'the last row in WorksheetName.
LastRowValue = Cells(LR, Col).Value

End Function
```